# How can I display an error message via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, text, validation, alert

I'm creating a form, and I'm validating it with JavaScript.  The way it works now, is if a value is not correct, it displays an alert stating that you need to enter text.  My question is, how can I change it so that instead of an alert, the text box will turn red, and something like: "This is required" will show next to the textbox.  I *think* I can solve this with jQuery, but I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions.  THANKS!

P.S. If you go to [yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com), click Sign Up, and click Create Account (without entering anything), you'll see what I'm aiming at.

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins/forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , I would use a jQuery Validation plugin which is at

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

You just need to add the css class "required" to the elements that you need to be validated

Answer (score 4):

You could create a CSS class with the following properties:

```
input.ERROR { border-color: red; }
```

Using jQuery, you can add this class to the input box with the incorrect value:

```
$("input[name=Address]").addClass("ERROR");
```

(assuming the input box with the name "Address" had the wrong value)

Comment: For example: `$("input[name=Address]").after("Error in input");`